# Why does flex-direction: column fix the flex layout of my code?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is when I resize the window, the `.gallery-1` image goes under to the below 2 images, but when I change the `flex-direction: column` of the `.gallery` it fixes the problem. I don't understand why; can someone explain?

```css
*---  Gallery section  ---*/


.main-gallery {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.main-gallery h1 {
}

.gallery {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   flex:1; 
  
  
}
.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.gallery-2 {
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.left-side {
  flex:1;
  margin-right:0.3em;
}

.right-side {
flex:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!--    gallery sections    -->
                <div class="gallery-1  gallery">
                  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="Room Gallery img ">
              </div>
     
                <div class="gallery-2 gallery">
                    <div class="left-side">
                      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="Room Gallery img ">
                    </div> <!--left-->
                  
                    <div class="right-side">
                      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="Room Gallery img ">
                    </div><!--right-->
                </div>
                
                <div class="gallery-3  gallery">
                  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="Room Gallery img ">
              </div>
              
            </div><!--    Main  Gallery End       -->
            
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elements shouldn't collapse below each other if you remove the `flex-wrap: wrap` style declared.